# Downloading CSV file with PHP

Tags: php, csv, header

I am trying to download a CSV file with PHP but I can not make it to get the dialog box.
I have changed the headers and used the readfile() function as shown [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

This is my code:

```
$nodeId = 'something';
$filename = "/var/www/dkar/ruralBroadband/ruralApp/rural/csvExports/$nodeId.csv";

header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename ="report.csv"');
readfile($filename);
```

** EDIT **

Tried also with this as suggested:

```
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="report.csv"');
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('report.csv'));
```

When I am checking the response in Firebug I can see the whole CSV file returned. Also the headers change into:

```
Content-Type    text/csv
Content-disposition attachment; filename ="report.csv"
```

So I can not figure out why I dont get the dialog box to save the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I didn't use the above method and I did that, which works fine and its more straight forward:

```
var ajaxurl = 'exportNodeData.php', // script to run
                data =  {nodeId:nodeId}; // data to pass
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {     
                    document.location.href = 'https://www.ruralauditor.gr/csvExports/'+nodeId+'.zip';

                });
```

This is the ajax request, which I execute in order to create the CSV file (which is also zipped). I then use this line:

```
document.location.href = 'https://www.ruralauditor.gr/csvExports/'+nodeId+'.zip';
```

in order to force the download of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Add these headers:

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="report.csv"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
```

Comment: inline? not attachment?

Comment: is `$filename` the file you wish to download? In that case, the content length should be of the `$filename` not of "reports.csv". I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I also tried this but it didn't work. Can it be related with my browser or something with the server?